# Boostrap 3 css vertical align two divs one top one bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment, responsive, word-wrap

> Issue: So vertical alignment issue is I have two divs in the last column and I'm trying to get one to stay at top and one to stay at the bottom regardless of how the central column grows.  I can work this out by using fixed heights but that's no good in this case.

[image: vertical image issue]

> **Here is my code example : [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3L5Lbwhn/1/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row" class="property-bundle"><!-- (x) number of these -->
    <div class="col-xs-11 wrapper">  
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 pull-left vendor">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-8 properties-list">                        
              <div class="row" class="property-line">
                 <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x140" /></div>
                 <div class="col-xs-10"><p>Flat 1</p></div>
              </div>

              <div class="row"><hr/></div>

              <div class="row" class="property-line">
                 <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x140" /></div>
                 <div class="col-xs-10"><p>Flat 2</p></div>
              </div>

              <div class="row"><hr/></div>

              <div class="row" class="property-line">
                 <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x140" /></div>
                 <div class="col-xs-10"><p>Flat 3</p></div>
              </div>                      
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-2 costs"><!-- costs column -->
              <div class="row total">
                 <h3 class="text-right">TOTAL: £1,2M</h3><!--stay at top-->
              </div>

              <div class="row" class="fees">  <!--stay at bottom-->                  
                 <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <hr/>
                    <p class="text-right">+ Materials £300K</p>
                    <p class="text-right">+ Build £100K</p>                                
                 </div>
              </div>      
            </div>      
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; margin: 15px;}

.vendor  {min-width: 120px;}

.properties-list {background-color: aquamarine}

.costs {vertical-align: top; min-width: 150px; vertical-align: center}

.fees {vertical-align: bottom; }

h3 {font-weight: 400}
h4 {color: green}

.total { margin-right: 0px; }
```

Comment: do you want it in right side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I simplified this a bit, but essentially flex did what I needed so many thanks to Edin Puzic for putting me on the right lines!  It also allowed me to fix the 1st and last col width and make the middle one dynamic horiontally too.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KjGZw/389/)

```
<div class="row-flex">
  <div class="col-flex-1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-flex-2">
    <div class="row" class="property-line">
      <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x140" /></div>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <p>Flat 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <hr/>
    </div>

    <div class="row" class="property-line">
      <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x140" /></div>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <p>Flat 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <hr/>
    </div>

    <div class="row" class="property-line">
      <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x140" /></div>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <p>Flat 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-flex-3">

    <div class="pos-top">
      <div class="row right-text">
        TOP right
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pos-bottom">
      <div class="row right-text">
        <p>
          BOTTOM right
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row-flex {
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row column;
}

.col-flex-1 {
  min-width: 200px;
  border-left: 1px #ccc solid;
  flex: 0 0;
}

.col-flex-2 {
  width: 80%;
  border-left: 1px #ccc solid;
  flex: 1 1;
}

.col-flex-3 {
  min-width: 200px;
  border-left: 1px #ccc solid;
  flex: 0 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.pos-top {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pos-bottom {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: green;
}

.right-text {
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try using `flexbox`

I just change your html like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-2 costs">
                <!--stay at top-->
        <div class="total">
           <h3 class="text-right">TOTAL: £1,2M</h3>
        </div>
                    <hr/>
                <div class="materials">
                    <p class="text-right">+ Materials £300K</p>
                    <p class="text-right">+ Build £100K</p>
                </div>                                
                 </div>
              </div>
```

Then I add on `costs` div `display:flex;`and on `total` div  `flex-grow: 1` This `flex-grow` will push materials on bottom of div.

You just need to add on `body`, `html`, `row` and `costs` div `height:100%`

Here is css:

```
.costs {
    vertical-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.total {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

You can see example on this link: https://jsfiddle.net/3L5Lbwhn/9/

Comment: I like the flex angle you have used but it doesn't line up top and bottom (inline with the middle column) precisely. I'll play a bit more with it though, thanks.